# WinSock2 c++ what happens when accept(...) method is called

Tags: c++, server, winsock2

I am following the Getting Started with WinSock guide ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/getting-started-with-winsock)) from Microsoft.

In my situation I have a java application that act as the client, and a c++ application for the server.

Here is the server code so far:

```
//all includes
int main()
{   
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET listenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET clientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints; 

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    //Initialization
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("WSAStartup success !\n");
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    //Resolve the server adress and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    listenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (listenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(listenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(listenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    clientSocket = accept(listenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //No longer need server socket
    closesocket(listenSocket);

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(clientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        printf("result : %d", iResult);

        //Receive data
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            printf("Message: %s\n Sending response to client... ", recvbuf);
            const char* response = "Hello from key/mouse emulator app server";
            iSendResult = send(clientSocket, response, sizeof(char) * (strlen(response)+1), 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(clientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(clientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(clientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

My understanding was that in the `do...while` loop it was listening to any incoming data from the client. So I tried to debug to check what kind of values I have in iResult when nothing is sent.

I found out using Visual Studio community 2017 that I could not go further this line :

```
clientSocket = accept(listenSocket, NULL, NULL);
```

And it would only go in the `do...while` when the client sent some data. 
So my question is what happens in the program when I reach `accept(...)` line?

Comment: It does what `accept()` is documented to do: wait until a connection is established. I'm sure that doing a Google search will find plenty of online documentation explaining how that system call works.

Comment: Why can't I go through the method on debug mode with Visual Studio ? There should be a loop where it listens if there is any established connection ?

Comment: @Logan WLv set a brakepoint on the line after your accept call. Close your client app. Start your server app and and wait a few seconds and then start yoir java client. Notice how your breakpoint isnt hit until you connect to your server with your client. Thats what accept does in blocking mode. it blocks executuon of the server code until a connection is established by a client.

Comment: @johnathan ok but what is blocking the execution so in the accept method there is  something like a while(checkingConnection) { //doNothing } ? Anyway to access this code from Visual Studio ?

Comment: @LoganWlv no, accept (afaik) it doesn't do a spinlock. It works with signals. There is no `while(condition)` loop within.

Comment: @bolov sockets have a few modes of operation on windows, and they model the Berkley socket stack but do not copy it exactly. by default all socket calls block unless you specify that you want asynchronous socket calls with WSAAsyncSelect or by completion ports, etc.  The call to accept blocks until a client connect request is received and a socket is created by the server for the client communication to occur.

Comment: @Logan Wlv the source code to the network stack is not available, but the source code to the Berkley sockets stack is. Does it really matter to you how they acheive blocking? It shouldn't. You just have a garentee that your program will not progress until you have a socket to communicate with a client. That is a perfectably acceptable model for socket code.

Comment: @johnathan Yeah it's not that important, but I just wanted to understand how does it work behind.

Comment: I appriceate and truly do encourage your courosity, but this question is implimentation defined and no one outside of Microsoft has access to that source code. But if your courious about things that can block the execution of code theres plenty of threading primitives you can look up, like std::mutex and std::lock_guard.

Comment: @johnathan yes, the `accept` method is blocking. My point was that it does not use a spinlock to block, but rather signals. You can easily check this by making a blocking call to `accept`. If a core usage goes to 100% while waiting then it has a spin lock (`while(cond)`), otherwise it uses signals to wait.

Comment: @bolov or a signal object, like a lock on a mutex!

Comment: @johnathan I personally don't see how a `lock` or `mutex` can be used to wait for incoming connections. Maybe a `condition_variable`.